# Firebase push notification not showing while App in foreground iOS

Tags: ios, swift, push-notification, notifications, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am sending push notification by using FCM and PushTry, While the app is in suspended mode (App is closed) notification is coming but while app in foreground mode (App is open) notification coming but not showing banner.

`didReceiveRemoteNotification` notification method is calling when app in foreground mode and print data but not showing banner.

**Code:-**

```
import UIKit
import FirebaseCore
import FirebaseMessaging
import IQKeyboardManagerSwift

@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

var window : UIWindow?

func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey : Any]?) -> Bool {
    FirebaseApp.configure()
    Messaging.messaging().delegate = self
    registerForFirebaseNotification(application: application)
    return true
 }

 func registerForFirebaseNotification(application: UIApplication) {
    if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
        //For iOS 10 display notification (sent via APNS)
        UNUserNotificationCenter.current().delegate = self
        let authOptions: UNAuthorizationOptions = [.alert, .badge, .sound]
        UNUserNotificationCenter.current().requestAuthorization(options: authOptions,completionHandler: { _, _ in })
 } else {
        let settings: UIUserNotificationSettings =
        UIUserNotificationSettings(types: [.alert, .badge, .sound], categories: nil)
        application.registerUserNotificationSettings(settings)
        }
     application.registerForRemoteNotifications()
      }
 }

extension AppDelegate: MessagingDelegate {

func messaging(_ messaging: Messaging, didReceiveRegistrationToken fcmToken: String?) {
    print("Firebase token: \(fcmToken ?? "")")
    let dataDict: [String: String] = ["token": fcmToken ?? ""]
    NotificationCenter.default.post( name: Notification.Name("FCMToken"),object: nil, userInfo: dataDict )
}

func application(application: UIApplication, didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken deviceToken: Data) {
    Messaging.messaging().apnsToken = deviceToken
}

    //UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [AnyHashable : Any], fetchCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> Void) {
    print("APNs received with: \(userInfo)")
}

func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, willPresent notification: UNNotification, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UNNotificationPresentationOptions) -> Void) {
    let content = notification.request.content
    print("\(content.userInfo)")
    completionHandler([.banner, .list, .sound]) // Display notification Banner
   }
}
```

**Print:-**

```
APNs received with: [AnyHashable("google.c.sender.id"): 0000000000, 
AnyHashable("google.c.fid"): 000000000, AnyHashable("google.c.a.e"): 1, 
AnyHashable("aps"): {
alert =     {
    body = 22eeee;
    title = 11;
  };
  "content-available" = 1;
 }, AnyHashable("gcm.message_id"): 00000000]
```

**App Notification Setting Screen:-**

[ScreenShot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3nu98.png)

**Question:** Can someone please explain to me how to show banner when app in foreground mode, I've tried with above code but no results yet. If i'm doing wrong please correct me.

Can someone please explain to me show notification banner?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: When your app is in the foreground ios won't show a banner.  You need to write code in `didReceiveRemoteNotification` to show the notification in your UI somehow

Comment: Actually, you need willPresent delegate method.

Comment: @Paulw11, if you don't mind, could you please share some code, how to show notification with the help of `didReceiveRemoteNotification` delegate method or give any reference.

Comment: @cora, i already added `willPresent` this delegate method.